# Firebase Crashlytics iOS: Cannot receive events even though the script seems running

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I know this can be a seemingly frequently asked question, but I cannot receive events from Firebase Crashlytics.
Of course I searched around for the previously asked questions, but none was my case.
If someone has any idea other than the things I've done below, please let me know.

### What I've done:

- Checked the build script (`${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run`) is running. It leaves this kind of message on the log and nothing looks wrong. Also, when I faked the path or filename just for double-cheking the build stopped with a script not found error.

```
Running upload-symbols in Build Phase mode
Validating build environment for Crashlytics...
Validation succeeded. Exiting because upload-symbols was run in validation mode
```

- Freshly downloaded `GoogleService-Info.plist` from the dashboard. This also looks like working because deleting or renaming this file gives me a build error(=file itself is recognized) and faking the bundle id inside the plist gives me a warning in the runtime(=file content is read). I believe this also eliminates the possibility that the event is being sent to somewhere else unexpectedly.
- Detached from debugger when testing. I think this is what most of people have experienced. I made sure of this hundreds of times by doing kill -> relaunch -> crash -> relaunch many times.
- Excluded crash testing code from launch process. This is also a common pitfall, and I of course wrote the crash code in a button event handler.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention.  I also made sure that the device (iPhone6) is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Note: For better debugging you should use the `-FIRDebugEnabled` flag in `Arguments Passed On Launch`. This worked for me:

1) Change your run script:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" -d
```

In your build output you should now see the API Key:

```
Running upload-symbols in Build Phase mode
Validating build environment for Crashlytics...
Arguments:
Debug mode enabled
API Key: <api-key>
Platform: ios
DSYM Paths: ["..."]
```

2) Manually initialize Crashlytics in your AppDelegate:

```
Crashlytics.start(withAPIKey: "<api-key>", delegate: self)
```

Launch the app, you should see the crashlytics output:

```
Crashlytics] Version 3.14.0 (144)
[Crashlytics] Running on iOS Simulator (iPhone), 13.1.0 (19A602)
[Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
[Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
```

3) Perform a crash (with debugger detached). After this you should see this output:

```
[Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
```

Comment: Thanks for your info!
It reports `[Fabric] failed to download settings Error` but
it also says `report submission successful` in the end.  Do you have any idea about what "settings" is?

Comment: When initializing Crashlytics, you need to use the key shown in the build log. Do not use the Google API key, as this is different than the Fabric API key. When you see the line `[Fabric] settings downloaded successfully` you know that it has been setup correctly

Comment: Is a key shown in the build log?? Can you provide a bit more detail?

Comment: You have to use the key that is shown in the build log when the run script is executed. With the `-d` flag you should see an output like this:
`API Key: <api-key>`

Comment: I can't see that even with `-d` flag.

Comment: Ah, sorry I found that. I was looking at the runtime log.  But it can print the key means it knows the key,  What's the meaning to specify that explicitly again? And if that's necessary why it's not documented officially?

Comment: I think this may be due the transition from Fabric to Crashlytics...maybe this will be fixed in the future